# Google Directory API convert timestamp to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, google-directory-api

I'm getting info about chromeos devices through the directory API.  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/chromeosdevices
The autoupdateexpiration field returns an int64 value for this.
In C# when I try to convert to a datetime with new DateTime(autoupdatexpiration) I don't get a valid date.
An example of a device returns this:  1843455600000
In the Google Admin console, the auto update expiration for this device is showing Jun 2028.
How do I convert this int to a DateTime with value Jun 2028

Comment: `new DateTime(autoupdatexpiration)` <-- The `DateTime(Int64)` ctor is intended for serialization scenarios, _not_ interopability.

Comment: `1843455600000` looks like a Unix timestamp graduated in milliseconds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Thank you.  It was indeed a Unix timestamp.  I didn't think about that.